Are others allowed to use my copyrighted figures in theses, without asking?
I recently got a citation warning from google. A book I have written, which is copyrighted by the publisher, was cited. It turned out to be a doctoral thesis, in which a figure from my book was copied, with the phrase "Reproduced from [x]" in the caption.
My questions is if this is actually legal. It is very unlikely that I will take action against a student, but they should have asked. I would have agreed unreservedly.
The copyright statement is as follows:

This work is subject to copyright. All rights are reserved by the
Publisher, whether the whole or part of the material is concerned,
specifically the rights of translation, reprinting, reuse of
illustrations, recitation, broadcasting, reproduction on microfilms or
in any other physical way, and transmission or information storage and
retrieval, electronic adaptation, computer software, or by similar or
dissimilar methodology now known or hereafter developed. The use of
general descriptive names, registered names, trademarks, service
marks, etc. in this publication does not imply, even in the absence of
a specific statement, that such names are exempt from the relevant
protective laws and regulations and therefore free for general use.


It is quite possible that the student requested copyright access from the publisher, and that they were granted access. Academic publishers usually give copyright permissions very easily when the data is to be used for a thesis.

I agree with @Harsha, when I used figures from another publication in my paper, the only contact I had was with the publisher. Why should they ask you? After all, the copyright belongs to the publisher, not you.

Thanks for the answers. If it had been my student, I would have recommended that the author was asked anyway, just a matter of courtesy, even if not legally necessary. Politeness matters.

Its also possible that such use might just scrape in under fair use rules, depending on where you are. In the US I believe this would fall under the specific Fair Dealing (research & study) exception.

@Anders if they had asked you, you gave permission, and they reused the figure without permission from the copyright holder, they could get into hot water. (Probably not in this case, but in general.)

@Anders I would not find that impolite at all. You are no longer the person who has anything to decide that. Personally, I would find it rather spammy would I receive such a request, as I am not the one who is able to decide anything anyway.

I would expect this to fall under fair use (or whatever equivalent in your jurisdiction). And there to be a duplicate already (don’t have time to search right now).

@MisterMiyagi, probably not fair use. figures have too much information and can be considered as "complete works" in themselves, unlike a sentence or so. And, as Allure says, the OP has no right to give permission if they aren't the copyright holder.

I don't think a PhD student in the last stage of the dissertation process needs the added "politeness" burden of reaching out to someone who plays no role in the decision and might never even respond.

@Buffy Works can be copied in their entirety and still come under fair use, provided other conditions are met. The amount copied is only one factor in the test.

While there is an international copyright treaty, details can vary from place to place. It would help you get the best answer if you can add the jurisdiction where the work is copyrighted.

@ToddWilcox It's not THAT important, but the book is copyrighted by the publisher in Switzerland, and the thesis was from a university which is also in Switzerland, which is surely just a coincidence. It is a multinational publisher.

A "citation warning"? I do receive mails from Google Scholar saying that my papers have been cited, but typically they are not warnings

Since the book is copyrighted by the publisher, it's indeed legal to use it without asking you. You no longer hold the copyright, after all.
You could find out if the author asked the publisher (i.e., the copyright holder) by reaching out to your contact at that publisher. It's pretty likely they did (and most publishers have an explicit form, example from Elsevier). If they didn't, then it's up to the publisher to take action, although they are admittedly also unlikely to do anything.

And the OP should be happy they got a citation.  Publications without citations are not so valuable.

I'd be wary that asking the publisher might make them feel compelled to pursue some sort of action against the student, which in my mind seems unnecessarily heavy-handed given the circumstances. Unless OP wants something to be done (which, I don't really see why? especially since OP says they'd have gladly granted permission if asked) then it's probably best left alone.

“You no longer hold the copyright” — That depends entirely on the agreement with the publisher. The phrasing in the question (“A book I have written, which is copyrighted by the publisher”) is somewhat vague and doesn’t make it clear if the book is exclusively copyrighted by the publisher or jointly copyrighted by the publisher and the author. If it’s the latter, which is quite common in Europe, the publisher would not be able to grant reproduction rights without asking the creator as well.

@JanusBahsJacquet To be honest, I don't know. I would assume it's exclusively the publisher.

"It's pretty likely they did [get the publisher's permission]" -- I'm not so confident for something like a Ph.D. thesis, but sure, it's possible.  Either way, however, it's quite right that this is primarily the book publisher's problem, not the OP's.

Certainly, I obtained permission for the figures in my thesis, and it was something discussed in our programme and lab. The usual phrase being "reproduced from X, with permission". I have no idea whether this is widespread elsewhere, of course.

It's only a doctoral thesis that does it? You are cited?
Seriously, if this were a journal paper or even just a conference paper, I would understand your question.
But it's just some poor soul that tried to make their doctoral thesis a bit more readable and included a didactically helpful diagram of yours with clear reference, maybe even just in the pressure of the last minute. Very few theses are read by anyone except the reviewers.
As others say, it's probably not even your copyright, as you may have signed it away.
And as Terry Loring says in the comment, you should be happy to get a citation.
Let it go.

… not sure I agree.  As I do not know of a case where a student would have to pay to include a figure taken from a paper or a book in a thesis, it costs nothing AFAIK to the student to just ask for permission.  Agreed that “Reproduced from [x]” mitigates the case for plagiarism, but otherwise I see no valid reason for not contacting the rightful copyright holder.  The student deserves to receive a strongly worded note from the copyright holder.

@ZeroTheHero If this were ordinary coursework, the student would almost certainly be covered under Fair Use in the US and I assume most other places as well. The thesis is probably the first thing the student has done that's not quite the same as ordinary coursework, yet it seems quite similar and it's not too surprising that they'd assume similar rules apply. At most, it seems like it could be a teaching moment, I don't think an admonishment is quite needed.

@BryanKrause agree it's a teaching moment.  I'm just surprised the supervisor wasn't on top of this.  I just came out of a thesis defence where the 2nd question by the examination committee was "Did you get permission to use the figures".

@ZeroTheHero The original question mentions the publisher is the copyright holder. We don't know if the student contacted the publisher and received permission. Without that information, there really isn't any valid judgement call on what the student deserves.

@DavidS at least in the case of physics journals I'm familiar with, publishers also require to get permission from first author (or corresponding author depending on the journal) of a paper/book.

@ZeroTheHero That is not the case for physics journals I'm familiar with. I'd be surprised if it's a very common practice, although I don't actually know.

You seem to have read the OP's post as a complaint. I read it as a question and nothing more. I don't see the need for condemnation here.

@DavidZ (At least some) APS journals do ask for that. From the most recent one I requested: "The American Physical Society (APS) is pleased to grant the Requestor of this license a non-exclusive, non-transferable permission, limited to Electronic format, provided all criteria outlined below are followed.  1. You must also obtain permission from at least one of the lead authors for each separate work, if you haven’t done so already."

@Buffy Maybe you are right. Still, in the legalistic atmosphere that is increasingly being promoted in academia, I like to pour cold water on the tendency to view everything through a rigorously formal lens. There is a place and time for a formally correct procedure (and there are, by all means, enough situations that call for such), and there is a place and time to (to quote my response or, if you prefer, the relevant movie) "Let it go". And with these considerations, ultimately, this remains my response to OP's question, even read purely as a question.

@Buffy Thanks! It was indeed a question and not a complaint.

@CaptainEmacs Agreed there is too much legalize around, but on the other hand the most important academic currency is recognition, not money, and it costs nothing to properly and correctly recognize the work of others.  I am not advocating paying $$, but the process of obtaining permission (for figures and such) is now much streamlined so this is a case where ignorance or carelessness should be combated, especially as students do get copyrights on the contents of their thesis.

@Anyon IIRC Nature journals (at least those for physics) have an equivalent wording requiring permission from the first author (which annoyingly may not be the corresponding author).

@ZeroTheHero Recognition is already achieved by citation. Permission is about the permission holder having the power to withhold the right to use them; it's about IP rather than recognition. Again: I am of the opinion that one should ask for permission for a journal or conference, but for a thesis, whose role is essentially to demonstrate the candidate's scientific prowess, I find the demand overkill. I have used a professional photographer's images in a paper, paid for and referenced, but this was crucial. Normally, it's so much effort that I avoid external images.

@ZeroTheHero In Nature, AFAIK, you even need permission to acknowledge someone. I am sure this is above the usual standard expectation.

@CaptainEmacs well... I suppose my threshold is at a different place than yours.  Where the threshold is may be field dependent, and it may be a different amount of hassle for different disciplines and/or journals, but in physics at least it's so simple  I find little excuse not to do it.

"Very few theses are read by anyone except the reviewers." << That strongly depends on the field. In some fields, PhD theses can be very popular, not for their original contribution but for their bibliography and literature reviews, which tend to be much more comprehensive than any other literature reviews available.

@Stef Point taken. But it is quite the exception, in my experience.

Other answers have addressed who is the owner of the copyright, but haven't mentioned "fair use" provisions, under Copyright Law.
Even if you were to show you did own the copyright, other people may copy it under certain circumstances. This varies by jurisdiction, but is likely to include people using your figures for scholarly purposes.
In the USA, for example, Title 17 U.S. Code § 107 - Limitations on exclusive rights: Fair use states:

Notwithstanding the provisions of sections 106 and 106A, the fair use of a copyrighted work, including such use by reproduction in copies or phonorecords or by any other means specified by that section, for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research, is not an infringement of copyright.

Whether it strictly applies in your case is a question for a lawyer.

Plus, if they cited it, it means OP's publication may be scientific or research-oriented in nature, and that would by definition mean it is supposed to be spread, used, copied, and improved upon.

@MrVocabulary: Copyright law doesn't allow willy-nilly copying based on whether the original publication is research-oriented. It allows limited copying based on whether the purpose of the copying in considered fair use. OP's publication could be a Disney movie, and fair use would still be fair use.

Fair use is a US concept. In EU countries, the equivalent concept of fair dealing and similar ones provide significant exceptions, usually defined at the national level. For instance, exemptions are for the purpose of criticism, review, or quotation, which are subject to proper justification. While I am a layman, my experience suggests that the type of source is a factor in justification, including academic contexts.

@MrVocabulary: Your first comment suggested that "by definition" a research publication may be intended to be copied. That paints the fair use/fair dealing copyright exemptions the wrong way around. I may not just reprint an entire book because it is research-oriented. Yes, the type of information may be a factor in determining if a usage is "fair", but there is no "definition" that makes it wholesale free to copy without permission. Your original comment was misleading rather than illuminating.

I can see how my comment may be seen as ambiguously phrased — to clarify, I did not mean a legal definition, but a clear characteristic.

It seems like just a citation warning, as just a notification that you were cited. You should be glad. It is the publisher that holds the copyright and it is their responsibility to deal with that. I am quite sure that the person who cited and used your figure first cleared it with the copyright holder. In the end, it has nothing to do with you.

What is it, exactly, that makes you sure the copyright holder granted permission?
